# Estimate the execution time of java program before program ends

Tags: java, time-complexity, execution-time

I was wondering how can I estimate a total running time of a java program on specific machine before program ends? I need to know how much it will take so I can announce the progress by that.

FYI Main algorithm of my program takes O(n^3) time complexity. Suppose n= 100000, how much it takes to run this program on my machine? (dual intel xeon e2650)

Regards.

Comment: yes, doable. dig deeper & try a littl

Comment: Run your program for `n = {1,10,100,...}` and try to approximate

Comment: @ArturMalinowski I can not do that. It takes so much to do that!

Comment: If it is so much time to run your program for a very small input, with complexity of O(n^3) you will end with months or years of processing.

Comment: O(n^3) is an approximate statement about how your program scales as n gets bigger. Its isn't an absolute measure of time. Two algorithms, both O(n^3), may take very different amounts of real time to process n nodes. What O(n^3) says is that if it takes T time to process 10 nodes, then it will take approximately 10T to run to run 100 nodes. To get an absolute value, you need to know T.

Answer (score 1):

In theory 1GHz of computational power should result in about 1 billion **simple** operations. However finding the number of simple operations is not always easy. Even if you know the time complexity of a given algorithm, this is not enough - you also need to know the constant factor. In theory it is possible to have a linear algorithm that takes several seconds to compute something for input of size `10000`(and some algorithms like this exist - like the linear pre-compute time RMQ).

What you do know, however is that something of `O(n^3)` will need to perform on the order of `100000^3` operations. So even if your constant is about `1/10^6`(which is highly unprobable), this computation will take **a lot** of time.

I believe   @ArturMalinowski 's proposal is the right way to approach your problem. If you benchmark the performance of your algorithm for some sequence known aforehand e.g. `{32,64,128,...}` or as he proposes `{1,10,100,...}`. This way you will be able to determine the constant factor with relatively good precision.

Comment: Is there any tool available that could simulate programs for different hardware? Or can estimate a running time?

Comment: @Alin not that I know of. Note that writing such tool could be quite complicated as generating a valid input is not easy task.